# U-SQL: How to skip files from analysis based on content

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a lot of files each containing a set of json objects like this:

```
{ "Id": "1", "Timestamp":"2017-07-20T10:43:21.8841599+02:00", "Session": { "Origin": "WebClient" }}
{ "Id": "2", "Timestamp":"2017-07-20T10:43:21.8841599+02:00", "Session": { "Origin": "WebClient" }}
{ "Id": "3", "Timestamp":"2017-07-20T10:43:21.8841599+02:00", "Session": { "Origin": "WebClient" }}
```

etc.

Each file containts information about a specific type of session. In this case it are sessions from a Web App, but it could also be sessions of a Desktop App. In that case the value for Origin is "DesktopClient" instead of "WebClient"

For analysis purposes say I am only interested in DesktopClient sessions.

All files representing a session are stored in Azure Blob Storage like this:

```
container/2017/07/20/00399076-2b88-4dbc-ba56-c7afeeb9ef77.json
container/2017/07/20/00399076-2b88-4dbc-ba56-c7afeeb9ef78.json
container/2017/07/20/00399076-2b88-4dbc-ba56-c7afeeb9ef79.json
```

Is it possible to skip files of which the first line already makes it clear if it is not a DesktopClient session file, like in my example? I think it would save a lot of query resources if files that I know of do not contain the right session type can be skipped since they can be quit big.

At the moment my query read the data like this:

```
@RawExtract  = EXTRACT [RawString] string
    FROM @"wasb://plancare-events-blobs@centrallogging/2017/07/20/{*}.json"
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter:'\b', quoting : false);

@ParsedJSONLines = SELECT Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple([RawString]) AS JSONLine
        FROM @RawExtract;

...
```

Or should I create my own version of `Extractors.Text` and if so, how should I do that.

Comment: does the file name already tell you if it is a DesktopClient Version of not? Or is this information basically in the file line of the file (so you have to read the file first) ?

Comment: The latter I am afraid. I have many, many files already so renaming them will be a hard thing to do.

Comment: @COR do you know if it possible to skip files based on user-defined metadata of an azure blob?

Comment: Well, what I could think of, would be to query the azure blob meta data using a custom user defined function in u-sql (C#, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-properties-metadata). That function would return the list of files needed. 

In a second step, you could then run your extract based on the function's result. I've never tried that. 

And Im not sure if that'd work; especially because of some U-sql restrictions regarding external IP calls. But it is definitely worth a try.

Comment: @COR in your opinion, would it be possible to check the metadata in a custom extractor, or does an extractor have no knowledge about the type of file it is processing?

Comment: my question is, where do you have the metadata about which type of files to extract? Do you have that information directly attached to the files or do you have it the blob storage container?

Comment: Attached to the files using metadata, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-properties-metadata#setting-and-retrieving-metadata.  Point is, I will need to call FetchAttributes on the blob. But I do not know if a custom extractor get info on the blob location.

Comment: Sorry for the long silence... I am actually on vacation and won't be back for another week. I think you should give it a try. I am not sure if dealing with the blob in the custom extractor will be considered as an external ip call and thus, be blocked. If it does, then you could definitely​ use Data Factory beforehand to FetchAttributes on the blob and filter the files, and then use ADLA for further intended transformation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer some questions that popped up in the comments to the question first:

At this point we do not provide access to the Blob Store meta data. That means that you need to express any meta data either as part of the data in the file or as part of the file name (or path).

Depending on the cost of extraction and sizes of files, you can either extract all the rows and then filter out the rows where the beginning of the row is not fitting your criteria. That will extract all files and all rows from all files, but does not need a custom extractor.

Alternatively, write a custom extractor that checks for only the files that are appropriate (that may be useful if the first solution does not give you the performance and you can determine the conditions efficiently inside the extractors). Several example extractors can be found at http://usql.io in the example directory (including an example JSON extractor).

Comment: I figured this it the way to go. Would be really nice if a custom extractor had some basic knowledge about the source like filename though

Comment: We are having a workitem on the backlog to expose such information either inside the extractor UDO model and/or as part of some column functions. Can you please upvote the current feature request at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/10948392-support-functionality-to-handle-file-properties-fr (and indicate in the comments which of the two - or both approaches - you would prefer)?